# Creating a delegate with unknown parameters and return type

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to create a method which returns a delegate of a given type, with a body running certain code specified in the function. i.e.

```
    public Delegate GenerateDelegate(Type delegateType)
    {
        // create a delegate of type 'Type'
        // specify the code of this delegate
        // return the delegate object
    }
```

If I knew the type, or at least parameters & return-type beforehand, I could obviously just return a delegate of that type, an anonymous one, with whatever code I want. However, the problem is that I want this to work for pretty much any type of non-generic delegate and I want to be able to make use of the parameters the delegate type has, and return the correct type.

I've taken a look at different options of using **ILGenerator.Emit()** or **CodeDOM** to achieve this. However I may want to do quite complex things within the returned delegate, and would prefer to be able to code this directly in C# as I'm not sure I can achieve this using IL or **CodeDOM**. As a pseudo-solution, in the same fashion as **Delegate.DynamicInvoke(params object[])** can take anonymous parameters, I'm thinking I'd like to be able to do something like this.

```
    public Delegate GenerateDelegate(Type delegateType)
    {
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, GetType().GetMethod("RunEvent"));
    }

    public static object RunEvent(params object[] parameters)
    {
        // some specified code, depending on contents of parameters
        return null;
    }
```

The **RunEvent()** can take any number of parameters as an object array, and returns object. Sadly, this does not work and throws the following exception:

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Somehow I think the object array parameters should be compatible with any combination of parameters a delegate may have, but the return type being an object, might return some object not compatible with the given **delegateType**, or if the **delegateType** returns void. This may cause some problems.

For my own usage, I know all the parameters and return-type at run-time, and can check for this to make sure everything is safe. Is there any way I can get something like this working?

Comment: *"object array parameters should be compatible with any combination of parameters a delegate may have"* – not really. They don't match `ref`/`out` parameters, they don't match value type parameters (without implicit boxing applied when you call such a method normally). Knowing absolutely nothing about method you're going to call seems like some very wrong way to go.

Comment: You are right. I didn't take into account ref/out parameters. It would be great to support that functionality as well, but for my current usage I don't need ref/out usage, if that would simplify the solution in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, it does however require me to use generics. In a way its a safer solution, as I'll need to supply the generator with the requested delegate and its types.

While the solution isn't quite what I was hoping for, it does solve the problem for me at the moment and answer my original question. I may however have to move to a more complex solution in the future.

If anyone can see a further simplification of this, please let me know.

*(I discovered this thanks to Anis suggestion on exploring Expression Trees, as it takes a similar approach.)*

```
public class DelegateGenerator<TDelegate, TReturn> 
    : GenBase<TDelegate, TReturn> where TDelegate : class
{
    public TReturn RunEvent() => runEvent();
}
public class DelegateGenerator<TDelegate, TReturn, T> 
    : GenBase<TDelegate, TReturn> where TDelegate : class
{
    public TReturn RunEvent(T a) => runEvent(a);
}
public class DelegateGenerator<TDelegate, TReturn, T1, T2> 
    : GenBase<TDelegate, TReturn> where TDelegate : class
{
    public TReturn RunEvent(T1 a, T2 b) => runEvent(a, b);
}
// etc

public abstract class GenBase<TDelegate, TReturn> where TDelegate : class
{
    public TDelegate GenerateDelegate()
    {
        var method = GetType().GetMethod("RunEvent");
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate), this, method) as TDelegate;
    }

    protected TReturn runEvent(params object[] objs)
    {
        // some code
        return (TReturn)result;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
public delegate bool myDelegate(int a, bool b);

var gen = new DelegateGenerator<myDelegate, bool, int, bool>();
var del = gen.GenerateDelegate();

var result = del(5, true);
```

Comment: @daniherrera Two of your links are identical, and one is the answer to someone elses question. For questions where I've marked my own as answer as solution it's where there hasn't been a complete answer and I figured out the problem, only to help others that find the question. Also, the one you linked where I marked my own I offered the to edit in the correct solution that I found and I would mark theirs as the solution.. Not sure what your point is, but if I'm doing something wrong let me know. :)

Comment: Got it. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go down the 'raw' IL-generation route. But consider using [expression-trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) if the body of the methods will allow for it.

Here's a simple example that simply returns the *default* value of the return-type, ignoring all the parameters (this is just a toy example; a real implementation would need to be a lot more complex - dealing with `out` params for example):

```
static Delegate CreateDelegate(Type[] parameterTypes, Type returnType)
{
   var parameters = parameterTypes.Select(Expression.Parameter)
                                  .ToArray();    

    var body = Expression.Default(returnType);    
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, false, parameters);    
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Usage:

```
Type[] parameterTypes = { typeof(string), typeof(double) };
var returnType = typeof(int);   

var del = CreateDelegate(parameterTypes, returnType);

//Output: System.Func`3[System.String,System.Double,System.Int32]
del.GetType().Dump();

//Output: 0
del.DynamicInvoke("abc", 5D).Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried this quite extensively (took some time to try it out), and ended up in a different solution which takes a similar approach, but it didn't require the use of expression-trees. Not sure if it's the best or final solution, but it works for now and does answer my question.